# googlemaps:turning the GPolyline cursor to pointer

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have a GPolyline , which pops up an info window when it is clicked. I would like to turn the default cursor when hovered over, from a hand to a pointer . Is there a way to access the GPolyline style?
here is my function

```
//add graph to point
function addGraph(data, x, y, color, desc) {
    //get map width and height in lat lon
    var d = map.getBounds().toSpan();
    var height = d.lng();
    var width = d.lat();
    var maxsize = 0.9;
    var pointpair = [];
    var increment = (parseFloat(height) / 10.0) / 100;
    var start = new GPoint(parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y));
    var volume = parseInt((parseFloat(data) * 100) / maxsize);

    pointpair.push(start);
    //draw the graph as an overlay
    pointpair.push(new GPoint(parseFloat(x + increment), parseFloat(y + increment)));
    var line = new GPolyline(pointpair, color, volume);


    var label = new Label(new GLatLng(parseFloat(y), parseFloat(x)), parseInt(data * 100) + "%", "f", new GSize(-15, 0));

    map.addOverlay(label);
    map.addOverlay(line);
    GEvent.addListener(line,'click',function(para)
        {map.openInfoWindowHtml(para,desc )});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working  :D

```
 GEvent.addListener(line, "mouseover", function() {
        $('#map').css("cursor" ,"pointer");
    });
```